# Creating a separate function forEach loop? Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to seprate the forEach loop into a function, allowing me to reuse the loop to create different objects ? I really do not want to copy and paste the loop many times

```
  createEnemies: function() {
    this.enemies = this.game.add.group(); // create a group of objects
    this.enemies.enableBody = true;

    var enemyArr = this.findObjectsByType('enemy', this.map, 'objectsLayer'); // find enemes from tilemap
    var enemy;
    enemyArr.forEach(function(element) {
      enemy = new SuperSmash.Enemy(this.game, element.x, element.y, 'enemy', +element.properties.velocity, this.map, this.player);
      this.enemies.add(enemy);
    }, this);
  },
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shure:

```
function loop(arr){
   arr.forEach(function(element) {
        enemy = new SuperSmash.Enemy(this.game, element.x, element.y, 'enemy', +element.properties.velocity, this.map, this.player);
        this.enemies.add(enemy);
}, this);
}
```

Use like this:

```
loop.call(this,enemyarray);
```

You could also do loop(enemyArr) but than this would be window...

The best solution would be to make loop a property of your game object (?)

```
loop:function(arr){
  ...
 }
```

Than you dont need the binding, as

```
MyGame.loop(enemyArr);
```

already binds this as MyGame.

//UPDATE AFTER OPs COMMENT//

You may have a look at the map function:

```
EnemyArr=EnemyArr.map(element=>new SuperSmash.Enemy(this.game, element.x, element.y, 'enemy', +element.properties.velocity, this.map, this.player));
```

This will replace your simple Objects in the Enemy Array with the SuperSmash Objects...

Comment: what is `this`? Have different context now

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this and so far it works well.

```
   createEnemies: function() {
        this.enemies = this.game.add.group();
        this.enemies.enableBody = true;
        var enemyArr = this.findObjectsByType('enemy', this.map, 'objectsLayer');
        this.loop.call(this, enemyArr, 'enemy', 'Enemy');
    },


    loop: function(arr, enemykey, enemytype) {
        arr.forEach(function(element) {
            var enemy;
            enemy = new SuperSmash[enemytype](this.game, element.x, element.y, enemykey, +element.properties.velocity, this.map, this.player);
            this.enemies.add(enemy);
        }, this);
    },
```

Comment: as this is based on my answer ( i believe ) it would be fair to press the green tick button, and by the way, you can simply do this.loop(enemyArr,"enemy","Enemy") as this is already bound to your game object

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can create a variable like var floop = function (data) {}
And reuse it. Just be sure to use binding if necessary to not to loose scope.

Comment: thats rather a comment.

Comment: Thanks everyone , I missed an important detail, evertime I run the for each loop , the object i create with the NEW keyword needs to change. I'm going to have to think of a new way for doing this(maybe with a json file that holds the enemy types). 

loop 1 -----------------
enemy = new SuperSmash.Enemy(this.game, element.x, element.y, 'enemy', +element.properties.velocity, this.map, this.player);

loop 2-------
enemy = new SuperSmash.Bat(this.game, element.x, element.y, 'bat', +element.properties.velocity, this.map, this.player);

Comment: @stckpete: leaving a coment somewhere will just notice the user youre commenting on.. and please put the code in your question, its hard to read